# Fetch Network Request Failed

Tags: react-native, expo

i'm running an react native with expo v33. I need to fetch data from a web server in json format using fetch

When calling

```
fetch('https://elpuente.io', {
        method: "GET",
      })        
      .then((response) => console.log(response))
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
```

I get this warning:

```
Network request failed

Stack trace:
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/vendor/core/whatwg-fetch.js:504:29 in onerror
  node_modules/event-target-shim/lib/event-target.js:172:43 in dispatchEvent
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:580:29 in setReadyState
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:394:25 in __didCompleteResponse
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/vendor/emitter/EventEmitter.js:190:12 in emit
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:366:47 in __callFunction
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:106:26 in <unknown>
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:314:10 in __guard
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:105:17 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
  ...
```

When using localhost everything works ok. I've also tried to fetch using ip address but get the same warning.

Thanks .

Comment: Problem is in Trust anchor for certification path not found.

Comment: Hi Oleg, thanks. Do you know how to fix this? Should be fixed in server side or app side?

Comment: Did you test in expo standalone app?

Comment: Yes, in standalone and published mode and same error. I tried using http and https and and same error.

Answer (score 0):

Can disable redirect on server to https and work with http

Comment: Oleg thanks for answer. I fixed it! There was a problem with ssl chain. I've updated the SSLCertificateChainFile of virtualhost in apache and now I'm fetching data from remote server.